# How to use :gt with a variable that contains a collection of JQuery objects

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use :gt with a variable that contains a collection of JQuery objects.

```
var $allIcons = $('.myIcons');
var $greaterThanFive = $allIcons.find(':gt(5)');
```

The "$allIcons.find(':gt(5)')"  call is not returning anything.  I have verified that $allIcons contains more than 5 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), the supplied selector is tested against each element; all elements matching the selector will be included in the result.

```
 var $greaterThanFive = $allIcons.filter(':gt(5)');
```

the [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements

OR

You can simply use

```
 var $greaterThanFive = $allIcons.slice(5);
```